# Magento2: Getting error when add new customer from admin after migration

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I am unable to add new customer in admin or unable to edit customer. i am getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 220 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(220): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('unsubscribe', NULL) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(84): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('unsubscribe', 'Null', Array) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(159): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php( in /opt/lampp/htdocs/letoilemigration/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 172
```

I have removed var and genrated folder also and ran all required command but still getting this error.

Anyone have an idea for that please?

Comment: have you done any customization related to the newsletter?

Comment: No I did not customize anything

Comment: added any extension recently?

Comment: No all the extensions are core extension.

Comment: Ok, try after `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`,`php bin/magento cache:flush`, `php bin/magento setup:static:deploy -f`

Comment: I have tried all the commands

Comment: error is related to Newsletter module.

Comment: I have disable the newsletter module but still getting the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82356/discussion-between-kunj-and-twinkle-systematix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted one row `eav_attribute` table where `attribute_id =164` that worked for me.

Comment: just a note to this, the entity_id listed here doesn't matter, it's just about any custom customer or product attribute you (or your developer) built in to the Magento 1 site. I had 3 to remove but i knew exactly what i'd written in.